# Any ideas on how to fix this query?

Tags: postgresql

I am having an issue getting this query to work. It runs, but nothing gets created. No csv file. Any ideas on how to fix it would greatly be appreciated!

```
COPY (SELECT CASE WHEN endpoint_group_id = 3 THEN “CO” WHEN endpoint_group_id = 8 THEN “NY” WHEN endpoint_group_id = 10 THEN “NC” WHEN endpoint_group_id = 11 THEN “UT” WHEN endpoint_group_id = 13 THEN “ID” END AS ‘location’ , CASE WHEN firmware_id = 7 THEN “6.0.0” WHEN firmware_id = 9 THEN “6.1.1” END AS ‘firmware_version’ ,name, unique_id FROM endpoint WHERE firmware_ID <> 12 ORDER BY endpoint_group_id ASC) TO '/tmp/filename.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, header);
```

Comment: Exactly what is wrong with the query?

Comment: It looks like it runs but nothing gets created. No csv file.

Comment: That information is relevant to the issue, so I've edited it into the question. In the future please try to include things like that in your question. Good luck!

Comment: I get an syntax error with that query because `“6.0.0”` is interpreted as a column name and dots aren't allowed in there and the quotes aren't actual double quotes (`"`). You should a) use standard ASCII quotes and b) enclose string literals in single quotes (`'`) not double quotes and aliases in double quotes not single quotes (or not at all if they don't require it). Looks like you did pretty much the opposite at some spots.

Comment: Sticky bit! Awesome! That solved it! Now, if I wanted it to automatically rename the "name" column and the "unique_id" column to "Name" and "MAC Addresses" respectively, how would I change the following syntax to do so ",name, unique_id"

Answer (score 0):

[sticky bit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9661424) has posted a comment but not an answer, so I'll write this answer for the benefit of future viewers.

The query raises a syntax error because you're using the `“` character instead of the standard `"` character. You should change that the “ characters to ".

Also, string literals should be denoted by `'` characters instead of `"` characters.